# Counting votes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, vote

I have a table, with the following columns:
id  name  vote

Each name is unique, and each vote is either null or contains a name.

I need a MySQL statement to return how many votes each person has, and who voted for each person.

I've been working on this for 3 hours, and I'm at a complete loss, so I honestly don't care how inefficient it is, or how you do it.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: From the looks of it, your DB design sounds questionable. Are you sure it's in 3rd normal form? If not, you probably need to redesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many votes:

```
select 
 count(*) as numVotes, 
 vote
from
 voteTable
where
 vote IS NOT NULL
group by 
 vote
order by
 numVotes desc
```

Who voted for each:

```
Select
 name,
 vote
from
 voteTable
```

... unless I'm misreading something, it should be that simple

Comment: worked, thanks! i was trying to make this work with sub queries and stuff, but apparently it's just that easy.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT name, count(*) as num_votes, GROUP_CONCAT(vote) as voted_by FROM table GROUP BY 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(name), id from your_table where vote is not null group by (name)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get number of votes per person:

```
select vote, 
       count(*) as nbr_of_votes 
  from table 
 where vote is not null 
 group by vote 
 order by nbr_of_votes desc;
```

To get who voted for whom you basically has to select the entire table, leaving out the nulls

```
select vote, 
       name 
  from table
 where vote is not null 
 order by vote;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT VOTE, COUNT(1) Number_Of_Votes,
GROUP_CONCAT(Name)
WHERE VOTE is Not NULL
GROUP BY VOTE
```